# Can anyone please explain this code from vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
if [DBFileName] = "" and doesfileexist([FilePath] & "_temp_main.csv") = 1 then

else
  if doesfileexist([FilePath] & "_temp_main.csv") = 1 then
     DeleteFile([FilePath] & "_temp_main.csv")
  end if

  Dim FSO
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  FSO.CopyFile [DBFileName], [FilePath] & "_temp_main.csv"
end iF
```

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. This doesn't appear to be valid code.

Comment: The last End If has no starting If.

Comment: That looks like VBA, not VB.NET. What do you think it does?